# Place Image to a corner inside a Text View

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uitextview

How i can create a view like [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUkiw.png) in iOS. I need to create a view so that image and the texts should be like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iOS 7 in `UITextView` there is `textContainer` property of type [NSTextContainer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextContainer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can  set there `exclusionPaths` property which is an array of `UIBezierPath` objects that define your images' shapes. The text will float around those shapes. After that simply add an image view in proper place above text view.